# How to change reaction time and typing speed on holding a key in suckless dwm?

Tags: x-dwm

In source code must be some function or variable for that, but I can't find it and I don't know how to even google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the speed of a keypress is handled at the level of the Xorg server. The `xset` command is what you are looking for.

The `r` option controls the autorepeat. Invoking with `-r`, or `r off`, will disable autorepeat, whereas `r`, or `r on` will enable autorepeat. If the server supports the XFree86-Misc extension, or the XKB extension (which it does), then a parameter of `rate` is accepted and should be followed by zero, one or two numeric values. The first specifies the delay before autorepeat starts and the second specifies the repeat rate.

For example, I have this command run every time I login (in `.xinitrc`):

`xset r rate 300 50`

This increases the autorepeat on holding all keys.